# how to get date value in jsp and update it to mysql

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets

I have to insert date dynamically to database, how should I get the text value and update it ?
I have tried the following code.

```
<input type="Text" name="tbox" id="${up.adId}" maxlength="15"size="18" value="${expiryDate}"><a href="javascript:NewCal(${up.adId},'mmddyyyy',false,24)">
```

`UPDATE classifiedads SET expiry_date='"+ textBox[i]+"' where`

in where what condition should be checked from the above code.

i want to save edited values in textbox to the database remaining untouched but as i am giving value of each textbox as expiry date initially , i am unable to write where condition for edited values please help me i am strucked .

if i update with out where condition null values are updated

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any framework with JSP?

Answer (score 1):

On servlet you would receive date in the form of `String`, you need to do following steps to get Date from this string date

- Validate String date for nullity and format
- Convert from String Date to Date instance using `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by changing the query with `to_date(<value-to-insert>,'<format>')`

Ex: `select to_date('2007-01-01 12:00:01 AM','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss pm') as dt from dual;`

in your case :

`UPDATE classifiedads SET expiry_date=to_date('"+ textBox[i]+"','mmddyyyy') where " e.t.c`

Let me know in case of any issues.

Comment: i want to save edited values in textbox to the database remaining untouched but as i am  giving value of each textbox as expiry date initially , i am unable to write where condition  for edited values please help me i am strucked  thanks in advance.